# Is there any way to automatically output all backbone.js triggers/events in the console?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there any way to automatically output all backbone.js triggers/events in the console so I can see everything that is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you would need to override the Backbone.Events 'trigger' method, and then call the code you want before calling back to the original method.

something like this should work:

```
var originalTrigger = Backbone.Events.trigger;
Backbone.Events.trigger = function(){
  console.log("Event Triggered:");
  console.log(arguments.join(", "));
  originalTrigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

i'm not sure off-hand, but you may need to slice the arguments into an actual array to call apply:

```
originalTrigger.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

Comment: Hrrm, In my code it throws a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined, Backbone.Events.trigger exists though. @Derick

Comment: i edited the code... should work now. still not 100% sure. i basically worked in my tests, tho

Comment: Awesome, thanks, and you do need to `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` I also just log `arguments` instead of `arguments.join(", ")`

Comment: Seems like it should work, unfortunately that does not log *any* of the wp.media's events in Wordpress' Backbone.js.

Comment: @NoBugs: Here is the variant for WP3.5's Backbone :              `var originalTrigger = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post.prototype.trigger;
wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Post.prototype.trigger = function(){
    console.log('Event Triggered:', arguments);
    originalTrigger.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
}`